How do I make a selection by value from JSON to Postgresql?
There are two fields in the order table: payment JSONB, products JSONB. Postgres16. Here is an example of the json that I am uploading:
[{"customerId":"17892","products":[{"ordering":1,"name":"Samsung"},{"ordering":2,"name":"Iphone","customFields":{"Color":"Red"}}],"payment":[{"currencyIsoCode":"USD","sum":500}]}]

Tell me how to do SELECT correctly, for example:

When products name = 'Iphone'
When Color = 'Red' in customFields in products
When sum is greater than or equal to 500

It seems to me that this is wrong
SELECT *
FROM org_test.orders
        WHERE (payment->0->>'sum')::numeric = 500
          AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM jsonb_array_elements(products) AS product
            WHERE (product->>'name')::text = 'Iphone'
          )
          AND 
        LIMIT 50


What you have proven is that demoralizing data into nested structures turns into mess. Create proper tables for this data and make your life easier.

You mean the data is denormalized and the developer is demoralized? @AdrianKlaver

@MarmiteBomber, that is a great one. What I get for dashing off a comment before heading out the door.

Please review [mre] and update the post with table DDL and the desired/expected output. The post doesn't adequately convey what it is that you're trying to achieve.

I have Postgres 14.10, but suppose, there is no much difference.
As far as I understand your example, you have a table:
CREATE TABLE order_table (
  customerId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  payment  JSONB,
  products JSONB
);

put some examples:
-- your data
INSERT INTO order_table (customerId, payment, products)
VALUES
  (
    17892,
    '[{"currencyIsoCode":"USD","sum":500}]',
    '[{"ordering":1,"name":"Samsung"},{"ordering":2,"name":"Iphone","customFields":{"Color":"Red"}}]'
    );

 --no_iphone_less_500
INSERT INTO order_table (customerId, payment, products)
VALUES
  (
     18003,
     '[{"currencyIsoCode":"USD","sum":300}]',
     '[{"ordering":1,"name":"Samsung"}]'
  );

here are your selects:

When products name = 'Iphone'

SELECT *
FROM order_table
WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM jsonb_array_elements(products) AS product
       WHERE product->>'name' = 'Iphone'
     );


When Color = 'Red' in customFields in products

SELECT *
FROM order_table
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(products) AS product,
         jsonb_each(product->'customFields') AS customField
    WHERE customField.key = 'Color' AND customField.value = '"Red"'
   );


When sum is greater than or equal to 500

    SELECT *
    FROM order_table
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(payment) AS payment_detail
        WHERE (payment_detail->>'sum')::numeric >= 500
    );

